# how to get text,value pairs in gwt suggestionBox

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a GWT SuggestOracle with custom object suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249430/creating-a-gwt-suggestoracle-with-custom-object-suggestions)

i need a autosuggest combobox for an ambiguous list of strings. but everey string has an unique id. this id is needed to know what the user has selected (send id back to server and do something with it).

how to implement this with the gwt's auto-suggest-comboBox "`suggestionBox`". Is there a way to get an List of id->name pairs (like with `listBox.addItem(String name, String value)`) into the `suggestionBox`? probably by overwriting `suggestionOracle`? (how to get the selected id of the selected name?)

or is this usecase better be implemented by another gwt `widget`?

thx in advance

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661222/gwt-suggestionbox-how-to-get-text-value-pairs-in-it

Comment: Check : GWT SuggestBox backed by DTO Model - http://eggsylife.co.uk/2008/08/25/gwt-suggestbox-backed-by-dto-model/ and                                                       Creating a Multi-Valued Auto-Complete Field Using GWT SuggestBox and REST at http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/gwt-rest-auto/